# Detecting Collision in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, collision-detection

I am currently making a program in OpenGL 3.1, and I am using the math libraries provided in the OpenGL Superbible (5th Edition). I want to be able to include collision in my program, but I am not sure how. From my research on the internet, I believe I need to first get the world coordinates of the objects I want to do collision detection with before I can go about detecting if they are colliding. How would I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect collision in webgl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467374/how-to-detect-collision-in-webgl) – although the other question covers WebGL and JavaScript, the concepts are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create some approximation whether specific element may collide with other elements (so called bounding box) .

I've been using NVidia Physx in the past and the bounding boxes can be seen on my movie in: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dC71st1xLr0

When you have bounding boxes you can easily tell whether objects MAY collide and the you analyze just these elements. Without this optimization it may be hard to do it because of large CPU consumption.

Comment: How would I obtain the world coordinates of an object in OpenGL. Do I need to know world coordinates before approximating?