# How to detect collision with a wall in a first person webgl game

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, blender

I am creating my first web game with `WebGL`, but i got stuck with
   collision detection. I created a scene, I can move around but when I hit objects I can go through them.

I imported my blender file with `assimp2json` library, so I got a
   `JSON` file . I still got the original blend object. I am using this [storage room](https://clara.io/view/7788e01e-f385-432d-8680-ef74506b3085) in my project.

Comment: Please be more specific. WebGL is a technology for graphical rendering. It does not contain a physics engine. You must pick/write a separate engine for this.

Comment: check this link [WebGL Physics and Collision](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/webgl-physics-and-collision-detection-using-babylonjs-and-oimojs--cms-24114) it might help you

Comment: @CWBudde
I would like to know how to detect collision between the player (first person) and the objects (walls, etc.) with javascript. I converted the .blend file to json with the help of https://github.com/acgessler/assimp2json and loaded it onto my canvas element with WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

As Monah as well mentioned, WebGL doesn't contain much code for simulating physics. It's just meant for rendering. Things like collision detection is a completely different topic.

You can do this 'by hand', but most probably you will reinvent the wheel or it will be less efficient (feature and performance wise). This is where 3rd party libaries will definitely make your life easier.

Beside the already mentioned [Oimo.js](http://lo-th.github.io/Oimo.js/index.html) there is also [Cannon.js](http://www.cannonjs.org/) and [others](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Physics-libraries)

You might also have a look at other SO posts like [How to detect collision in webgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467374/how-to-detect-collision-in-webgl)

Comment: I **know what WebGL is (only drawing the scene)**, but I don't know how to implement CD with a converted blend file with the lib assimp2json. I have vertices of my mesh, it's normals and faces + everything I must create buffers for. I looked the manual and tuts for Oimo, but didn't even  import it because, I don't know how to use advanced tools, like npm. I also found three.js, but the tutorials are detailed for 3rd person view.

Comment: I guess your question is too broad (maybe that explains the downvotes). Try to narrow your question a bit further. Often you'll see that either your (more) specific question has already been answered or you need to dig deeper into the topic beforehand (by reading more about collision detection in general, data structures [of your input data] and tools).